# How should I add more memory to root folder

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, memory-usage, storage

So I followed a tutorial that told me to partition my memory as follows -

20GB in /   (i.e. the root folder) and

the rest(150 GB) in /home   (i.e. the home folder)

Pictures from the tutorial:-
[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9hS0.png)
[Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2tIt.png)
[Img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKmDU.png)
(I know the picture is showing 15GB for root but I was told in the instructions to assign at least 20 so I did)

Now the issue is that I have run out of space on my root folder and I want to know if there is a way to give more memory to / (root) folder from the /home folder.

Comment: You can add storage space to the root partition, but there is no way to add memory to any folder.

Comment: you can shrink the `/home` partition on the right, move it to the right, and then extend the `/` partition to use the space you emptied out. In the future, you can put home and root on the same partition, unless you have some specific reason not to.

Comment: @Esther is correct. However have you investigated what is using all that space? You may have something growing out of control. ncdu is a good tool to check that out.

Comment: Whatever tutorial you followed is either outdated or a poor source of information. The minimum requirements for Ubuntu Desktop are 25GB. 20GB is under the minimum requirements and considered insufficient.  You also don't need a home partition and it is not recommended or offered in the default installation. It's rarely useful. Don't follow sources that are outdated or sources that are not authoritative. There's lots of bad information out there. Always follow official documentation first.  Here's the [official tutorial to install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).